# How to assign a new value to elements of an array using nested indices?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros((5,3))

In [44]: data   
Out[44]:    
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [45]: data[[0,1,2]] = 2

In [46]: data   
Out[46]:    
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
   [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
   [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [47]: data[[0,1,2]][2]   
Out[47]: array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])

In [48]: data[[0,1,2]][2] = 3   

In [49]: data[[0,1,2]][2]   
Out[49]: array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])
```

I was expecting the last result to be [3., 3., 3.]. Why replacing elements using double indices isn't working? Is there a way to change elements of an array using double indices?

Comment: Why not `data[2] = 3`?

Comment: This is just an example for simplicity. My actual data is (50000,3) that I need to slice with one criteria and then slice again with another criteria and then replace the elements with a value.

Comment: Maybe you can combine the two criteria together using logical operator and then do the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
data[[0,1,2]][2] = 3
```

`data[[0,1,2]]` is a copy of part of `data`, not a `view`.  The expression is modifying that copy, not `data` itself.

```
In [298]: data=np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
In [299]: data[[0,1,2]]
Out[299]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [300]: data[[0,1,2]][2]
Out[300]: array([6, 7, 8])
```

This assignment works:

```
data[[0,1,2]] = 2
```

because the 'advanced-indexing' is right before the `=`.  In the first case it is separated by another layer of indexing.

Answer (score 2):

The way that Python evaluates `data[i][j] = x` is to first evaluate `tmp = data.__getitem__(i)` then call `tmp.__setitem__(j, x)` on that temporary object. In numpy's case, when you evaluate `data[[1,2,3]]` using a list to index the array, then you are creating a new array with a copy of the data at those locations. We can't create a view on `data` because the list may have indices that are scattered around, even duplicates. So the `tmp` object is not connected to the original `data` object. The assignment `tmp[2] = 3` happens, but then `tmp` is thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

That is very weird. It must be related to the structure of numpy.array. From my experience with numpy, array slicing is done with data[outerindex,innerindex] instead of conventional Python lists  data[outerindex][innerindex].

If you do

```
data[[0,1,2],2] = 3
```

you would modify data as you intended:

```
>>>data
array([ 2., 2., 3.],
      [ 2., 2., 3.],
      [ 2., 2., 3.],
      [ 0., 0., 0.],
      [ 0., 0., 0.])
```